# Phantoms and Proxies - lead to ghostly error

Tags: haskell, proxy, phantom-types

I am working on a project where I keep track of the db-schema I use via a phantom type - that has a `KnownSymbol` - which is the schema name.

Just the other day I came upon the following problem - which I don't understand:

Why is it impossible to define `withoutProxy` or to rephrase it - why does GHC assume that `test` is of kind `*` instead of `Symbol` in `(Proxy :: Proxy test)`, although the type signature says otherwise and `ScopedTypeVariables` is enabled.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures      #-}
module T where

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

newtype Phantom (x :: Symbol) y = Phantom y

withProxy :: (KnownSymbol test) => Proxy test -> Phantom test ()
withProxy _ = Phantom ()

withoutProxy :: (KnownSymbol test) => Phantom test ()
withoutProxy = withProxy (Proxy :: Proxy test)
```

The error I get is most confusing

```
> ghci test.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling T                ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:14:27: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘*’ with ‘Symbol’
      Expected type: Proxy test
        Actual type: Proxy test
      Use -fprint-explicit-kinds to see the kind arguments
    • In the first argument of ‘withProxy’, namely
        ‘(Proxy :: Proxy test)’
      In the expression: withProxy (Proxy :: Proxy test)
      In an equation for ‘withoutProxy’:
          withoutProxy = withProxy (Proxy :: Proxy test)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Then enabling `-fprint-explicit-kinds`

```
Prelude> :set -fprint-explicit-kinds 
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling T                ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:15:27: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘*’ with ‘Symbol’
      Expected type: Proxy Symbol test
        Actual type: Proxy * test
    • In the first argument of ‘withProxy’, namely
        ‘(Proxy :: Proxy test)’
      In the expression: withProxy (Proxy :: Proxy test)
      In an equation for ‘withoutProxy’:
          withoutProxy = withProxy (Proxy :: Proxy test)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: FYI, check `tagged` package, your `Phantom` is mono-kinded `Tagged`.

Comment: ah - nice - but I don't think I will change the type - in the existing project I have a `DB schema a` type that represents the schema I am querying - for I compare the data of two schemata that have the same tables but different data. there I use the schema tag so I do not compare a data set with itself and make sure the comparison "objects" have different schema but same content type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: add `forall`

```
withoutProxy :: forall test. (KnownSymbol test) => Phantom test ()
withoutProxy = withProxy (Proxy :: Proxy test)
```

Without it `test` on the second row, is different from the one above.

---

Or, don't add type-annotation at all:

```
withoutProxy :: (KnownSymbol test) => Phantom test ()
withoutProxy = withProxy Proxy
```

---

Or you could add `{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}`, and then things will unify also, as `Proxy :: Proxy test` will be `forall k (test :: k). Proxy k test`, where `k` is a kind.

Comment: Thanks - this just helped to simplify a lot of functions by removing a (now) unnecessary `Proxy`-parameter for each of them!